# Replace text surrounded by *** with <b> and </b>

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say I have a string

```
var myString: String = "This ***is*** my ***string***"
```

Now I'm searching for a way to replace the stars with html-bold tags.

After replacement the code should look like:

```
"This <b>is</b> my <b>string</b>
```

What I've done so far:

```
var boldPattern : RegExp = /\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*/; 

while(boldPattern.test(goalOv[gCnt][1])){
    myString = myString.replace(boldPattern, "<b>"+myString+"</b>");
}
```

This ends up with an endless Loop (because I'm assigning the string to itself).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good at regular expressions, but I think this simple solution will do the trick:

```
var boldPattern : RegExp = /(\*\*\*)/; 
var myString: String = "This ***is*** my ***string***";
var count:int = 0;
while(boldPattern.test(myString))
{
    if(count % 2 == 1)
        myString = myString.replace(boldPattern, "</b>");
    else
        myString = myString.replace(boldPattern, "<b>");
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, but please be aware that it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Gio said, that looping isn't the best way of replacing globally. You should instead do the following to avoid looping and have replacement in one pass over the string.

```
var boldPattern :String = "This ***is*** my ***string***";
var myString:RegExp = /\*\*\*([^*]*)\*\*\*/g;
var replText:String = "<b>$1</b>";

myString = myString.replace(boldPattern, replText);
```

Also, if you want to do it more correctly to allow for myString have have string of 1 or 2 *, you can use:

```
/\*\*\*(([^*]+\*{0,2})+)\*\*\*/g
```